# Replacing oracle specific notation (+) with LEFT JOIN and where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

Lately the (+) has been causing some issues for me, maybe it's depreciated by now.
Now I want to replace the (+) notation with LEFT JOIN, but I can't seem to get the syntax in order.

This is what I have:

```
SELECT x.a, y.a, z.a
FROM x, y, z
WHERE x.k = y.k(+)
AND x.p = z.p(+);
```

How can I replace the (+) with a LEFT JOIN?

-EDIT- I've read the "duplicated" answers, and few of them have accepted answers (no wonder why)

I could not solve my problem according to those.
The answer provided here was spot on and solved it - marked it as accepted.

I got another one that is a little bit more confusing (to me)

```
FROM a,b,c
WHERE b.a  = '101'
AND a.a    = '202'
AND b.c    = a.c
AND a.d    = c.d(+)
AND ROWNUM = 1;
```

Again, I want to replace the (+) with LEFT JOIN

Comment: Start with 2 tables. Do `x left join y on x.k = y.k` and `y left join x on x.k = y.k` - which one returns the wanted result?

Comment: SELECT x.a, y.a, z.a
    FROM x left join y
    on x.k = y.k
    left join z
    on x.p = z.p;

Comment: After your edit, you seem to be asking a new question. Best to do this as a brand new question and link back to this one if relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent syntax would be:

```
SELECT x.a, y.a, z.a
FROM x LEFT JOIN
     y
     ON x.k = y.k LEFT JOIN
     z
     ON x.p = z.p;
```